# Can you have two local extrema between next two roots of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

You can have ($\Delta<0$) brackets that don't make real roots.

Zero points on $R$ argument graph are but effect of $(x-r_n)$ roots.

So, can you have two local extrema between near roots? If not, can you please provide a proof?

Comment: Exactly 2 or 2 or more?

Comment: @tomKern you can write of exactly $2$ if proof for $\geq{2}$ is too long, or if you know the polynomial that have $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^4-x^2-1$ has three local extrema between its roots. You should be able to show that there cannot be exactly 2 local extrema by considering the intervals where the polynomial is increasing and decreasing. At a local extremum it switches.